# using moment.Js to create current date and time by giving user defined values for time

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

Suppose I gave a value as 4:30
I then split them into something like this ['4' , '30'].
I want to use moment to format it into something like this 
moment("2010-10-20 4:30", "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm");  // parsed as 4:30 localtime
any clues..?

here the date will be todays date.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by

```
var moment = require('moment')
moment("2010-10-20 04:30").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"); // will produce '2010-10-20 04:30'
```

More format examples:

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // November 9th 2016, 11:47:05 am
moment().format('dddd');                    // Wednesday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Nov 9th 16
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2016 escaped 2016
moment().format();                          // 2016-11-09T11:47:05+01:00
```